Xcode Issues importing library only for iOS
I'm using PopupView library on a iOS / visionOS project, but the library is not visionOS ready, and unfortunately gives a small compilation error even if I don't use it. So I excluded it and seemed that I was able to compile for visionOS, but from some time ago I'm getting compilation errors again. My approach:

Import the module only for iOS:

import SwiftUI
import WebKit

#if os(iOS)
import PopupView
#endif

(In a similar scenario I needed to separate the if macro from the rest of imports for some reason)

Embed the library only for `iOS``


Am I missing anything else?
